Generator Xcode toolset specification field buildsystem=1 is not allowed with Xcode 15.0.1
./make-project.sh 

-- cmake version 3.28.2
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:10 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0025 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0054 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:19 (project):
  cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
  call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
  both commands.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (project):
  Generator

    Xcode

  toolset specification field

    buildsystem=1

  is not allowed with Xcode 15.0.1.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

trying to build x265 project;
cmake --version -> 3.28.2
xcode --version -> 15.0.1
devices -> mac pro m3 pro

Try to update Xcode

You have to set another buildsystem for your toolset.
If you're using CMake presets type "toolset": "buildsystem=12" or
if you call it directly cmake -GXcode -T buildsystem=12.
"buildsystem=1" was allowed for Xcode 13.x
